# C# Parallel long-running interations are two times slower than sequential ones

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have this simple code

```cs
public struct Test
{
    public (int, int) A;

    public Test((int, int) a)
    {
        A = a;
    }
}

// On my PC, `Environment.ProcessorCount` gives 8. 
Enumerable.Range(1, 8).ToList()
    .ForEach(i =>
    //.AsParallel().ForAll(i =>
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var n = 100000;
        Span<Test> tests = stackalloc Test[n];

        for (var j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            for (var k = 0; k < 2 * n; k++) ;

            tests[j].A = (j * 6, j * 7);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{i}. {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    });
```

This version executes each iteration in about 8 seconds. If I comment out `.ForEach(i =>` and uncomment `.AsParallel().ForAll(i =>`, then each iteration takes about 16 seconds, which is 2 times more.

I understand there is overhead due to context switching, but I can't believe it should slow down the code twice.

My goal is to run code like this (no locks, almost no heap allocation) on a computer with ~100 CPUs, so I'm trying to make the best out of parallelization.

I'm running .net5.0 on Win10.

Comment: Do you have a CPU with HyperThreading?

Comment: @harold Yes, I do

Comment: Then it completely makes sense, because your CPU only has 4 physical cores and you're running 8 threads on them. That's not to say that HyperThreading is useless, but it relies on the competing sibling-threads being able to "fill each others gaps" and this kind of code doesn't really have such opportunities.

Comment: So to be clear, that means a 4x speedup is being spread out over 8 tasks, making the individual tasks half as fast. That's approximately harmless, it's not a 2x overhead.

Comment: @harold That makes sense. However, even if when I changed it to 4, the code stays 2times slower :/

Comment: That's really odd. I wanted to reproduce it, but HT is disabled on my machine for reasons that have to do with using Intel VTune and it would be a bit annoying to reconfigure so I gave up. The result with HT disabled was as expected: tasks took about as long as when single-threaded (a little slower, 5.9 seconds vs 5.3 seconds)

Comment: Is the `Span<Test> tests = stackalloc Test[n];` relevant to the problem? What happens if you remove this complexity, and just have a simple loop inside each iteration? `for (var j = 0; j < Int32.MaxValue; j++);`

Comment: I would be really surprised if each iteration ran faster. Try a stopwatch outside the loop and measure the different of total execution time.

Comment: @harold I ran a few more tests and in my case, it's 4.3s vs 3s, with 8 replaced with 4, and specifying explicitly `.WithDegreeOfParallelism(4)`. Not sure what to think.

Comment: Your code isn't doing anything so it ends up measuring the parallelization overhead. There's no data either, so `AsParallel` doesn't really have any data to process

Comment: @PatrikBak `PLINQ` is meant for data parallelism. That means, processing lots of in-memory data using all available processors. To do that, it partitions the data into as many partitions as there are cores and uses one worker task per partition. This is done to reduce the synchronization overhead. In your example though, there's no data. `AsParallel()` is used to just spin up the cores and allocate RAM.

Comment: @PatrikBak a *correct* benchmark would be to create a really big array up front and use `PLINQ` operators to process it, eg `data.AsParallel().Sum(i=>i*6);`. **BUT** as with all parallel algorithms, acceleration is constrained by synchronization and calculations that need to be performed sequentially.  If you need to access all previous array items in each iteration, you can't parallelize computation to begin with. If you can rewrite your algorithm to eg carry over, parallelization is possible.

Comment: So what's the *real* computation you want to accelerate?